# How do I create a hashing algorithim based on a combination of two variables in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hashlib

Im new to python and working on hashing algo.

I have a dataframe-

```
df2
Out[55]: 
         CID                 SID
0        2094825             141
1        2327668             583
2        2259956             155
3        1985370             100
4        2417177              47
         ...             ...
1030748  2262027             100
1030749  2232061             100
1030750  2027795             169
1030751  2474609             100
1030752  2335654             169

[1030753 rows x 2 columns]
```

How do i use the hashlib python library to get a hashing algorithm such that each combination of CID and STD gives me a unique encryption such as CID 2262027 and SID 100 is fj6x55 and CID 2232061 and SID 100 gives another unique encryption of f6223xi, etc. As long as the combinations are unique. I want unique encryptions. If they repeat then the encryption should be same.. Im open to other suggestions like one hot encoding too incase hashlib is not working. So far I am getting an error -

```
import hashlib
x = hashlib.md5(df2['SID'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-44772f235990>", line 1, in <module>
    x = hashlib.md5(df2['SubDiagnosisId'])

TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required
```

Comment: Based on your sample, `SID` looks a lot smaller than `CID`.  What is the maximum possible value of `SID`?

Comment: i think the max SID value is 583. CID and SID are not related. However,a combination of the two is needed to onehotencode or hash so that I can compare an array of values to another array of values.

Comment: What kind of data does `hashlib.md5()` accept as input?

Comment: @AMC: all hash functions take a string as input, or any buffer-like object.

Comment: @Basil I appreciate the willingness to help, I was just trying to nudge OP in what I think is the right direction ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at this one:

`hashes = df2.apply(lambda x:hashlib.md5((str(x[0])+str(x[1])).encode('utf8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)`

Some explanation:

`df2.apply` takes a function, in this case an anonymous `lambda` function, as well as the axis over which we want to apply the function. In this case, `axis=1` applies over each row.

Breakdown of the hashing function:

The anonymous function takes one argument `x`, which consists of two columns.  We break down x into `x[0]` (the first column CID) and `x[1]` (the second column SID).

Here, we have two choices.  We can either convert the integers into strings and concatenate the strings as I've done here, or multiply the CID value by some constant that is at least `max(SID)`.  However, I think string concatenation may not be unique enough for this case.  The better approach may be the following:

`df.apply(lambda x:hashlib.md5(str(x[0]*1024+x[1]).encode('utf8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)`

You noted that the max SID value is 583, so I chose the next available power of 2 as the multiplier.  This effectively left-shifts all CID values by 10 bits so that all 10 LSB bits are now zero. Then we fill those LSB bits with SID values using addition.

Either way, the final representation needs to be an encoded byte string, hence the `str(integer_stuff).encode('utf8')` part.  Finally, we enclose that result inside `hashlib.md5()` and call `.hexdigest()` to retrieve the hexadecimal string representation of the hash.

Improvements to my approach as far as Pandas itself is concerned are welcome :) but I think my hashing approach itself is quite sound.

**EDIT:**

In order to join the result to the original DataFrame, try the following:

```
# Calculate the hashes. This gives you a Series.
hashes = df2.apply(lambda x:hashlib.md5((str(x[0])+str(x[1])).encode('utf8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)
# Create a DataFrame from the above Series
df_hash = pd.DataFrame(hashes, columns=['hash'])
# Join the hashes with the original DataFrame
df2 = df2.join(df_hash)
```

Tested with a short set of data, so it should work for you too :)

Comment: this maybe a rookie question but im new to python. How can I append the final output to the original df2 dataframe? I have used the output of df2.apply(lambda x:hashlib.sha1(str(x[0]*1024+x[1]).encode('utf8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)

Comment: Hi is there a reason you chose to dothe first approach and not the better approach u mentioned below? I was wondering in the better approach you mentioned df.apply(lambda x:hashlib.sha1(str(x[0]*1024+x[1]).encode('utf8')).hexdigest(), axis=1)

Comment: Oops, I was just inconsistent with the hash algorithm there. You can use any fundamental hash function of your choice :)